# Is the MegaProtoUser's password hashed in the lift framework?

Tags: hash, lift

I am planning on using the lift's mapper's megaprotouser and I am wondering if I need to hash the passwords before they are inserted into the database, or does it already take care of that?

Answer (score 0):

The MegaProtoUser will not obscure the password by itself, but it uses MappedPassword, which provides that functionality. Check https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/persistence/mapper/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/mapper/MappedPassword.scala to see how this is achieved.